# Problem with importing products in magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, import, csv

Value for **'size'** attribute contains incorrect value, see acceptable values on settings specified for Admin in row(s): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

[image: This is my csv, i used for export product from magento 1.9 at 2.4.1]

Comment: Yes. values would be wrong in size column, share your csv file.